# How to minus time with Python

Tags: python, time

I'd like to get the time before X seconds before 
`datetime.time.now()`. For example, if the `time.now()` is `12:59:00`, and I minus `59`, I want to get `12:00:00`.

How can I do that?

Comment: [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[You can use time delta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) like this:

```
import datetime

print datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=59)
```

Comment: Doesnt matter much, but OP wanted to subtract the seconds, not minutes.

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha I used his example as my example...oh well

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha  Looks like minutes to me: **12:59:00 so If I minus 59, I want to get 12:00:00**

Comment: Thats absolutely right. My bad, I need to concentrate more :)

Comment: And actually almost everyone else saw it as seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
d = datetime.now()
d = d - timedelta(minutes=59)
print d
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=59)
```

Should do the trick

You can read more about timedelta on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#available-types):

> class datetime.timedelta
>
> A duration expressing the difference between
>   two date, time, or datetime instances to microsecond resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try dateutil:

```
datetime.datetime.now() + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(second=-60)
```